# Ошибка в mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Использую стандартные настройки

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Все запросы переписывает и переадресовывает правильно, но когда ввожу http://localhost/index то выдает 404 ошибку. Подкажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: У вас в файле index.php точно присутствует гет запрос с название index?

Comment: мой index.php выглядит пока так <?php
echo "request = " . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; он должен работать для любого запроса

Comment: создал 2 файла, проверил, все работает так как надо, проблема у вас видимо в чем-то другом.

Comment: @Manitikyl, спасибо за инфу